# Removing git rerere from my global configuration

Tags: git, github, vcscommand

I came across this git configuration seeing that helps me reduce recursion and I have been able to resolve a merge conflict just once and it gets resolved automatically whenever such conflicts show up again. But now I don't want to resolve this conflicts automatically again ease how can I remove this configuration setting  from my git global settings.

Comment: Git settings are held in `.gitconfig` in your home directory - have a look there and see what config options are set and modify any as necessary.

Comment: Thanks @match I was hoping there is a script I can write on my command line to remove the settings

Comment: You could script it with e.g. `sed` and `awk` by setting the opposite of the values you set in the first place... if you don't have the original tutorial/example to hand you'll just need to 'reverse engineer' the config and compare it to the defaults in a new repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This command disables ReReRe in your user config (i.e. in all your repos):

```
git config --global rerere.enabled false
```

You can omit the `--global` to do so in only one repo.

You can also set this for only one *command* like this:

```
git -c rerere.enabled=false merge ...
```